# Hot reload / fast refresh issues and VSCode in Docker devcontainer

Tags: reactjs

Apologies first of all, these may be some basic questions as we're just picking up an internal app which has been orphaned with some staff changes. Until we get some proper React resources hired again, we need to get some quick fixes in.

The issue is that even making smaller fixes the lack of hot reload in VSCode is painful! If I hit save on say packages.json file I do get the server to "recompile" but it does not generate any new content for the pages. Saving any .js pages and new changes does nothing for the server to reload.

I've read up about the various approaches, as a start trying to figure out what is the current setup of the React app.

In packages.json this is configured:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
```

Which means `npm start` kicks off react-scripts to start the server? We are using v5 of react-scripts.

I've found the various suggestions to add to env vars:

```
FAST_REFRESH=false
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

None of which have helped. I've also found potential issues with VSCode + WSL/Docker not being able to detect file changes, which is the `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING` recommendation. However, not sure how it is detecting packages.json changing but not any other file?

But it does not look like we are using nodemon which is what some of these solutions are for. I can see that react-native has fast refresh by default, but that is also not what we're using.

Any ideas how to get the hot reload going? Or what else to look at?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally tracked down a fix in a few minutes after posting here, classic. Here's the solution:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11879#issuecomment-1069553776

And I got rid of the env check line like the next commenter said since it's always running in a dev env in VSCode.